# Is it okay to mention my work experience?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, recruitment, resignation

I graduated from college with a bachelor's degree on Information Technology last May 2018. I wasn't a talented programmer during my college years but I was able to provide necessary output during assessments.

Fast forward to October 2018. After 14-16 interviews, I've finally landed a job with the role of an Associate Software Engineer. Before getting deployed to projects, we had to take this full-stack bootcamp. I was expecting face-to-face lessons. However, most of it was just taking online classes.

I did learn from the online classes but not all of them were effective to me. I did my best every time we had assessments on our bootcamp.

Fast forward to January 2019, I received my results from the bootcamp. I failed with a score that I can't even mention. I know I've exerted effort but I didn't make it. I even had to work beyond my shift and end up sleeping in our training room (it was my choice) to complete the assessments. I'm not the only one doing this though. Most of us were doing it.

For now, I'm assigned on the bench with no project deployments. I think that I'm going to be laid off soon because of my results.

To be honest, I have a love-hate relationship with programming. But I feel like it's not my primary skill.

I'm going to be applying to a different company with the role of UI/UX/Interaction Designer. Since I'm currently on probation, would it be okay to apply to a different company? If so, Is it okay if I mention my current working experience during the interview?

I was arguing with my mother (who was an HR before) that I shouldn't mention my working experience. But I know for a fact that there's going to be a background check.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

You haven't been fired - yet. So I'd first consider your options. For all you know the assessments were very difficult, only a tiny fraction of people passed, and they're considering next steps for everyone. Can you talk to your manager about your test score? You could ask what the likely next steps are now, if there's any roles you could shift to within the company that might be a better fit, talk about retakes, etc.

It could well be that the best move is for you to leave before they let you go, but don't jump to that conclusion without exploring other options.

> Since I'm currently on probation, would it be okay to apply to a different company?

Sure. Probation makes it *easier* to leave, not harder - you usually don't need to give much notice at all while on probation (details will be in your contract.)

> Is it okay if I mention my current working experience during the interview?

Missing out your current work experience may be more harmful than adding it in, because otherwise you'll have the inevitable question of "What have you done from when you graduated last May until now?". You'll then have to make something up that doesn't come back to bite you later - and by later I mean *any* time during your employment there. Lying isn't a good option, ethically or practically.

However, leaving during your probation period does smell a bit fishy to future employers, so be prepared to answer questions about what you did in your role and why you chose to leave. It's not necessarily a deal breaker, but it will make some employers cautious.

Comment: Something along the lines of what you have expressed to us is a perfectly fine answer, "I was working at XYZ doing A but my experiences there led me to understand that I'm a better fit for a job doing B". An honest answer that shows you have reflected and have good self-awareness is a very positive thing for a potential employer.